# Is it a good practise to use many valuelistenable builders instead of setState in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, setstate, state-management

I am making a flutter app and on one of the pages, I have many changing variables.
I am confused if I should use `ValueListenableBuilder` for all the variables or I should just use `setState` for all the variables.

Comment: I think it is ok & better to use stateState for all.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends. If it is a really simple `widget` with not that many variables changing, just use `setState`.

However, if you have MANY variables that has to change constantly. You'd better use `ValueListenableBuilder`, and actually that's one of the reasons to use the state management.

for example, take a look at the code below.

```
class SampleStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SampleStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<SampleStatefulWidget> createState() => _SampleStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _SampleStatefulWidgetState extends State<SampleStatefulWidget> {
  final _variable1 = 'hello';
  final _variable2 = 'world';
  final _variable3 = 'foo';
  final _variable4 = 'bar';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_variable1),
            Text(_variable2),
            Text(_variable3),
            Text(_variable4),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for the above code, if you use `setState`, the whole widget will be drawn again even though you just updated `_variable1`.

however, if you use `ValueListenableBuilder`, it will only update that part where `_variable1` is in.

Therefore, if it is a complex `widget` with bunch of variables that constantly change, use some libraries that will help you manage states such as `Provider` or `Riverpod`. (I personally really don't recommend `GetX`)

or you can create your own `BLoC` for `BLoC Pattern`, or you can also use library for `BLoC` as well.